# \usepackage{epigraph} changes the size of the whole text

Tags: formatting, margins, fontsize, epigraphs

I wanted to write in my thesis a quotation. Therefore I used the epigraph package in the following way:

```
\vspace*{0.2\textheight}

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{1\textwidth}
\noindent\epigraph{\LARGE{"\itshape{\textgreekfont\catcode`~=12 Kaὶ man\texttheta 'anw mὲn oῖa drᾶn m'ellw kak'a, \texttheta umὸs dὲ kre'isswn tῶn ἐmῶn bouleum'atwn, ὅsper meg'istwn aἴtios kakῶn brotoῖs}}"} {Euripide,  \textsl{Medea},vv1078-1080}
\bigbreak
\vspace*{0.07\textheight}
\Large{\textit{"But passion, that cause of direst woes to mortal man, hath triumphed o'er my sober thoughts"}}

\clearpage
```

Somehow this piece of code affects the whole remaining text, reducing the margins of the page and increasing the font size. Can you help me understanding why? Thank you

Comment: \Large doesn't take an argument. It is a switch.

Comment: To make it a bit more obvious: Use `{\Large text here}`. The syntax you currently have is wrong, but a mistae many starters are doing.

Comment: yeah I solved the problem thanks to @UlrikeFischer who made me realize it was a switch. But thank you as well!